# Why does jQuery fadeIn() not work when used after an interrupting fadeOut()?

Tags: jquery

I have something I want to fade in when the user does something. I want to fade it out when an event occurs. If the user does something, I want to fade it back in again (and again, fade it out when an event occurs).

Take a look at [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLLs6/1/) for an example. In this scenario, I want to fade in the "fadeP" tag when the user clicks "Click Me". I have a setTimeout to fade it out again (instead of my event listener). The timeout will fire before the fadeIn completes. It will stop the fadeIn (also clearing the animation queue) and fadeOut. If a user clicks "Click Me" again (potentially before the fadeOut completes), I want to fade the "fadeP" tag back in.

Click "Click Me" several times (either allowing time for the element to appear and dissapear or not, it doesn't seem to make a difference). Each time, the fadeIn fades the element in slightly less. I want it to fade the element in just as much each time the user clicks.

It's something to do with the `stop()`. It seems to remember that at the point the fadeIn was stopped, it had a certain opacity, and considers this opacity to be the completely faded in opacity. When you come to fadeIn again, it fades to the "remembered" opacity, but doesn't get there, because it is stoped, which causes it to remember that opacity as the completely faded in opacity and so on.

I need it to stop fadeIn when an event fires and fadeOut. I need it to stop fadeOut when an event fires and fadeIn. I need fadeIn to attempt to fade to the same opacity each time. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for good question I was wracking my brain trying to figure out what I've done wrong when the code appeared fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. You can track this in firebug. At the end of fade out, he sets the opacity back to the value he started from and also `display: none`. You can workaround this with setting opacity back to `1` or even better to `''` (for IE) when `fadeOut` is completed.

```
fadeP = $('#fadeP');
clickMe = $('#clickMe');

clickMe.click(function(){
    fadeP.stop(true).fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        fadeP.stop(true).fadeOut('300', function() {
            $(this).css('opacity', '');
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLLs6/2/)

### EDIT

I've modified the code to work with your comment. You could animate the `opacity` by yourself to start from the current value.

```
fadeP = $('#fadeP');
clickMe = $('#clickMe');

clickMe.click(function(){
    var currentOpacity = fadeP.css('opacity');
    fadeP.stop(true).show().css('opacity', (currentOpacity  < 1) ? currentOpacity  : 0 ).animate({opacity: 1});
    setTimeout(function(){
        fadeP.stop(true).fadeOut(5000, function() {
            $(this).css('opacity', '');
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLLs6/4/)

### EDIT 2

The final solution in collaboration with the OP ;-)

```
clickMe.click(function(){
    if(fadeP.css('display') == 'none') fadeP.css('opacity', '0');
    fadeP.stop(true).show().animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function () { $(this).css('opacity', ''); } );
    setTimeout(function(){
        fadeP.stop(true).fadeOut(1000);
    }, 500);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLLs6/9/)

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem for the circumstance where fadeOut is able to complete. However, there is a scenario where it will not behave as desired: If the user keeps clicking "Click Me" before the fadeOut completes, the fadeOut will be stopped. The fadeIn that then occurs does not fade properly. Se [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLLs6/3/) with updated durations that make this easier to replicate. You could potentially work around this by jumping to the end of the fadeOut animation (`stop(true,true)`) and resetting the opacity, but I would rather fadeIn from current state.

Comment: That does the trick, thank you. I might be inclined to alter it to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FLLs6/7/) so that if the opacity happens to be 1 when the user clicks (for some reason), it doesn't go and re-fadeIn. What do you think? It's a shame it's not doable with the fadeIn shortcut function, but this is close enough.

Comment: It's fine. Yeah, I think the fade functions are not optimal.

Comment: Actually, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FLLs6/8/) is even better. There's no need to set the opacity to '' with this approach, so no need for the fadeOut callback. If you fancy updating your answer, I would be happy to set it as accepted.

Comment: Did that. Btw. the `function () { $(this).css('opacity', ''); }` is important for IE after fade in with `opacity`, so the fonts look not distorted. I've added that in the solution.